# How can I change my code so that I don't have to use a script for all single record?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So here it is by browsing my records each time I have to create a code with the ID how to make just one function for all the records?

```
$tbody .= '<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#img'.$idImage .'").click(function () { $("#img'.$idImage.'").toggleClass("minresize") } );  
});
</script>';

$tbody .= '<td><img id="img'.$idImage .'" class="minresize" src="'.ASSETDIRECTORY.'uploads/'.$value.'" alt="'.$value.'" title="'.$value.'"></td>';
```

Comment: Anyway, it works very well this way, all the images are independent and minified at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is working perfectly. Thank you Luc Laverdure your comments put me on the right track.

```
<img class="minresize" src="'.ASSETDIRECTORY.'uploads/'.$value.'" alt="'.$value.'" title="'.$value.'" onclick="$(this).toggleClass(\'maxresize\');" >
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<img src="<?php echo ASSETDIRECTORY.'uploads/'.$value; ?>" alt="<?php echo $value; ?>" title="<?php echo $value; ?>" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('minresize');" class="minresize" />
```

Comment: It could have worked but unfortunately the script maximizes all images from the start.

Comment: I assume it just needed the initial class: class="minresize"